# Mongoose createConnection and Document.prototype.save()

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I am building a multi tenant app with only a few connections (max 3 or 4) on the same mongo host. What I am really doing is establishing mongoose connections at server startup and store it in a context object.

```
// For each tenants
tenantConnection(name, uri) => new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    const connection = mongoose.createConnection(uri, {
      useCreateIndex: true,
      useNewUrlParser: true,
      useFindAndModify: false,
      retryWrites: false,
      useUnifiedTopology: true
    })
    connection.on('connected', async () => {
      const MessageModel = connection.model('Message', Message) // <- Message is a classic mongoose Schema
      ...
      return resolve({ connection, models: { Message: MessageModel } })
    })
  })
```

All works well except when I am trying to use the prototype `.save()` (same with `Model.create({...})`. When I try to create a new record, the function stuck, no callback are triggered nor any error.

```
const { models: { Message } } = tenant
const messageRecord = new Message({ content }
await messageRecord.save() // -> Stuck here, nothing happens
```

At this moment, the only way I have found is to use `UpdateOne({}, {...}, {upsert: true})` to create records but I'd rather like to use native mongoose prototype `.save()` to trigger the setters from my schema.

Does anyone has any idea of what I am doing wrong ?

Comment: For starters, I think you are overcomplicating the connection setup and the model declaration, you can just start the connection, bind the connected event to the connection, and in parallel you can create the models, mongoose queues up all the things being done before it connects, for my is something related to the `this` context in the model, is missing something along the way.

Comment: I have been trying to declare the models before the `connected` event, and after, directly in the controller where I use it & unfortunately it still acts the same :( .I have read similar issues, but almost every time the unique answer is to use the `connect()` instead of `createConnection()` methods. But it won't suit my needs as I need several  db connections.